# How do I use an SQLCMD variable to define a table name?

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

So, using SSDT on Visual Studio 2013, I can specify a Database name...

```
create view vSample1 as 
select * from [$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.TableName
```

I can also do this with a four part name

```
create view vSample2 as 
select * from [$(RandomServer)].[$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.TableName
```

But when I try to do this with the TableName, I get errors...

```
create view vSample3
select * from [$(RandomServer)].[$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.[$(RandomTable)]
```

It gives me an error similiar to

```
Error:  SQL71561: View: [vSample3] has an unresolved reference to object [$(RandomServer)].[$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.[$(RandomTable)].
```

I've been looking at the SQLCMD variables window in the project settings and have verified that the $(RandomTable) variable is defined as TableName, but it still gives me build errors.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: out of interest, why do you want a random table name? Have you looked into using synonyms instead?

Comment: @EdElliott One of our vendors has a product that we've deployed into four different environments.  That product has a non-deterministically generated schema... in one environment, the table might be named [KeyType124], and in another environment, it's [KeyType133].  I was hoping to simplify the querying of the database in each environment by using SSDT to generate one set of queries that I could deploy to that environment in the form of views.   Then all you have to remember is vNames or vAddresses instead of KeyType133.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pre/post deployment script to create such view using sp_executesql and dynamic query.

```
exec sp_executesql N'create view vSample3 as
select * from [$(RandomServer)].[$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.[$(RandomTable)]'
```

Comment: SSDT would then see that string as a string instead of an sql statement:  Then it wouldn't run validation or refactoring against it.

Comment: Just try it, It will work although it won't be validated. I am afraid you can't use variables in scripts which are being compiled/builded.

Answer (score 1):

I would use synonyms - create a table which matches the actual table and create a synonym that points to that, then reference the synonym in the view or just reference instead of the view. You need this so you get it to compile and you get the good stuff like references etc.

Then when you deploy to each server just deploy the correct synonym to the correct server.

(Then kick your vendor in the b&DD$ for such an annoying system)

Comment: Doesn't this have the same issue though?     The following statement still gets a similiar error about [$(RandomTable)] being unresolved:

CREATE SYNONYM Sample3 FOR [$(RandomServer)].[$(RandomDatabase)].dbo.[$(RandomTable)]   

Just to be clear, I want for this solution to be integrated with SSDT, and I also cannot modify the Vendor's database (it's in the EULA), so somehow I need to be able to use a variable to deploy the view/synonym/whatever.

Comment: yes so in ssdt create a synonym and a fake table that has the same definition as the real table - then when you deploy, change the synoym to point to the actual table (which is different in each db). If you don't have a table in SSDT it won't be able to work out the definition etc (things like columns) - you don't need to deploy the fake table

Comment: I appreciate your advice, but at that point, it seems like you're putting makeup on an elephant.  I don't want to work around the issue by creating extra objects in my databases (objects that it sounds like I would only need in my development environment)...  I want the variable to work.    If this is the only choice that I have, it's one thing, but I'd rather just have an answer as to what I need to do to get SSDT to recognize the table based on the SQLCMD variable, just as it does with the database and server.

Comment: what are you using ssdt for? I ask because one of the main benefits is validating your code is correct when you compile - if you use a variable pointing to a non-existant table it can't validate that it is correct. You also have a pretty unique environment so it isn't going to be straight forward!

Comment: in my development environment, I would have the variable point to KeyItem123 where it is correct.   When I deploy the dacpac to the qa environment, I would deploy it using sqlpackage /variables:RandomTable=KeyItem324 (or whatever).   Yes, validation and refactoring are just some of the reasons that I want to use SSDT.